# Auto complete for text box using jquery in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have implemented code for auto complete in text box using ajax result. I have used below code to implement auto complete in text box

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-15">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tableOneTextBox" placeholder="Value" >
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
 $("#tableOneTextBox").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var tableDetails =
            {
                TextBoxValue: $("#tableOneTextBox").val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: domainName + "api/autocompletetextbox",
                data: tableDetails,
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item, value: item };
                    }))
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Rendered html in view:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="tableOneTextBox" placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off">
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 217px; top: 188px; left: 760px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1">01 - Chennai</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1">02 - Coimbatore</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1">03 - Kanchipuram</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1">08 - Bharuch</li></ul>
<span role="status" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><div>4 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</div></span>
```

**Issue**

Value rendered but the view like suggestion list not shown. Please help me.
I have tried lot of examples. Please let me know your suggestion it would be help full for me.

Comment: Have you included the relevant css files?

Comment: yes added please find in question i have used css in html. Please let me know if you have any other css list. @StephenMuecke

Comment: You have the scripts in the wrong order - `jquery` needs to be first

Comment: I have used script as your said also but not working. @StephenMuecke

Comment: What is not working. What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Following error thrown 365f1e7a34ff4d82af491f221c2dee05/arterySignalR/ping?requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A58389%2Fuserhome&browserName=Chrome&_=1504678671093 404 (Not Found) @StephenMuecke

Comment: A `404` means that the url your navigating to does not exist

Comment: 404 means that the designated route is unavailable. Verify `RouteConfig` and check how you generate URL from autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 1):

Put the jquery libraries in the right order like:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and try again, as all other libraries are based on `jquery`, so it must be the first library in your application.

Comment: I have used script as your said also but not working. @Mayanak

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No error shown @ Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i have missed to change below thing,

1. Changed Z- index.

   ```
   $(".ui-front").css("z-index","10000");
   ```

Now auto complete working fine as below image

[image]